# Vaadin DateField with empty value and placeholder

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a problem with Vaadin DateField using custom empty value.

```
LocalDate emptyDate = LocalDate.parse("1900-01-01");

DateField field = new DateField()
{
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return getValue() == null || getValue().equals(emptyDate);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate getEmptyValue()
    {
        return emptyDate;
    }
};
field.setPlaceholder("yyyy-MM-dd");
field.setValue(emptyDate); // Shows "1900-01-01" instead of placeholder
field.setValue(null); // Shows placeholder "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

I expect to see placeholder when value is equal to empty value, but it only works when value is null. Docs of DateField#setPlaceholder states "*Sets the placeholder text. The placeholder is text that is displayed when the field would otherwise be empty, to prompt the user for input.*" so it seems this does not work as one would expect?

Overriding #formatDate(LocalDate) doesn't work either:

```
@Override
protected String formatDate(LocalDate value)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        return getPlaceholder();
    }
    else
    {
        return super.formatDate(value);
    }
}
```

Using Vaadin 8.6.1

Comment: Does "getValue().equals(emptyDate);" return true? You can debug if you put this statement in a separat variable or with the "watch-function" of your ide.

Comment: Yes it does @Charlie

Comment: > I expect to see placeholder when value is equal to empty value

"Your" **emptyValue** is not literally empty (its '1900-01-01'). Place holder works only when the field value is literally empty, '1900-01-01' is a valid non-empty value for **DateField** (according to **Vaadin** and not according to you) and hence it will not show the place-holder.
This behaviour is indeed the expected behaviour.

Comment: As a workaround, can you overwrite setValue such that a value of emptyDate is transformed to null?

Comment: @VikrantThakur null is not the only definition of empty.  HasValue#getEmptyValue() (implemented by DateField) says "Returns the value that represents an empty value. By default HasValue is expected to support null as empty values. Specific implementations might not support this.", so it seems one should be able to redefine what value is considered empty. This also is in line with docs of DateField#setPlaceholder which uses the word "empty" rather than "null".